# stuck at Displaying Updated Array Data

Tags: reactjs

I have an array   `List`  and I'm using the `.push()` method to add new elements to it and then `concat` the input with List in  `Onclickadd`  method but its not  updating the array to display the items in to-do

```
import React from 'react'
import './App.css'

class App extends React.Component {
constructor(){
  super()
    this.state={
        List: ['potato']  
    }
  }

  onAddChange=(event)=>{ 
    this.setState=({
           input: event.target.value
        })
  }

  Onclickadd=()=>{
     console.log('clicked')
     this.setState=({List: this.state.List.concat(this.state.input)})
  }

  render (){
    return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>TODO LIST</h1>
      <input onChange={this.onAddChange} type='text' placeholder='Add Items'/>
      <button onClick={this.Onclickadd} className='btn'>Add</button>
      <ol>
          {this.state.List.map((items, keys) => {
            return <li key={keys}> {items}</li>
          })}
        </ol>
    </div>
  );
} 
  }
   

export default App;
```

Comment: `this.setState(...)` instead of `this.setState=()`

Comment: this.setState(...)  gives me TypeError: this.setState is not a function

Comment: there is no `.push()` in this code, I guess it's about that because you shouldn't update the `state` directly with push, if you add the part of code that push being used on it, it would be better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.setState=...` is the issue in your code. It is a function call there is no assignment using `=`.

You have done the same mistake in two places

Change the `onAddChange` to

```
onAddChange=(event)=>{ 
      this.setState({
             input: event.target.value
          })
    }
```

and

`Onclickadd` to

```
 Onclickadd=()=>{
       console.log('clicked')
       this.setState({List: this.state.List.concat(this.state.input)})
    }
```

Working example => https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-galois-ih7w4?file=/src/App.js:294-418

Answer (score 2):

`this.setState` is an function witch expects an object, you are trying to assign the value, instead off `this.setState=` use;

```js
this.setState({
   input: event.target.value
})
```

```js
class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state={
            List: ['potato']  
        }
    }

    onAddChange=(event)=>{ 
        this.setState({
            input: event.target.value
        })
    }

    Onclickadd=()=>{
        this.setState({List: this.state.List.concat(this.state.input)})
    }

    render (){
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <h1>TODO LIST</h1>
                <input onChange={this.onAddChange} type='text' placeholder='Add Items'/>
                <button onClick={this.Onclickadd} className='btn'>Add</button>
                <ol>
                    {this.state.List.map((items, keys) => {
                        return <li key={keys}> {items}</li>
                    })}
                </ol>
            </div>
        );
    } 
}
   
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

More info about `setState` can be found [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. I recommend you to add `value={this.state.input}` to the input like following :

`<input value={this.state.input} onChange={this.onAddChange} type='text' placeholder='Add Items'/>`

2. The syntax of `this.setState()` is not right, it's like this :

`this.setState({ List: this.state.List.concat(this.state.input) })`
`this.setState({ input: event.target.value })`